# Why is "der" used for both male nominative and female dative?

Tags: etymology, article, history, definite-article

> Der Mann hilft der Frau.

Why is the same definite article used for male nouns in nominative and female nouns in dative? Is there a deep connection, or just a coincidence? Have they always been the same historically?

|  | m | n | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nom | der | das | die |
| akk | den | das | die |
| dat | dem | dem | der |

Comment: You should think of them as two entirely different words that happen to be homophones. I'm not proficient enough in the matter to write this up as a complete answer though… ^_^;;

Comment: Why not? Also in English »the« is used for both male nominative (***The** boy is young*) and female dative (*I gave it to **the** girl*). It's even worse in English: You use »the« in all genders, all cases and all numbers (singular as well as plural).

Comment: Just going by the German Wikipedia page on Old High German, female dative was dero/deru and later lost the vowel at the end, merging with "der". But I would leave an answer to someone who actually understands this stuff.

Comment: When a specific morpheme serves one particular purpose in a language, it often reappears in another role: -en is use both for infinitives and for certain adjective endings, der/die/das are reused as articles *and* two different types of pronoun, -er can denote both certain plurals and comparatives (and English -s signifies both verbal 3/singular and nominal plural). This happens far more often than chance would explain, so there must be a general principle at work, but it isn't particularly well understood.

Answer (score 12):

I second deceze's comment on your question. *Der* (nominative, masc.) and *der* (dative, fem.) are just homophones that are the result of the declination of the article.

German definite articles grew out of the old demonstrative forms *dër*, *diu*, *daz* and have also been used as relative pronouns.

There are even more cases (no pun intended) of articles that cline to *der*:

| Singular | männlich | weiblich | sächlich | Plural | m/w/s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nominativ | **der** | die | das | Nominativ | die |
| Genitiv | des | **der** | des | Genitiv | **der** |
| Dativ | dem | **der** | dem | Dativ | den |
| Akkusativ | den | die | das | Akkusativ | die |

Answer (score 2):

As I've searched about 2 hours, there is no overlap in history - for nominative and Dative.

> From the nominative case being used, we may fairly assume that it was set up in AD 120, when the Emperor was in Britain.
>
> The Dative Case In English The Old English language, current until approximately the time of the Norman Conquest in 1066, had a dative case.

So, there is no deep historical connection and it's just an easy coincidence.

Note: I'll add , if I find more information. Just enough to satisfy your curiosity.